# Css sibling (~) selector not working on checked property

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Please take a look [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ec622hop), menu from left side should slide in and out on checkbox checked property, but my css is not working, can anyone help me please.
In my code menu is currently set to left:-240px, because it should be slide in to left:0 on checkbox checked.

my sibling code doesn't seem to be working, please help

```
#menuToggle.checked ~ .menu { position:absolute; left:0; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in the syntax when you use `.checked`. `.` is a class selector.

What you are aiming for should be with a colon

```
#menuToggle:checked ~ .menu { position:absolute; left:0; }
```

See it [corrected](http://cssdeck.com/labs/4tgywrza)

Comment: Oh damn, I couldn't even find out what i did there, Thanks so much for pointing this out. Thanks

Comment: @ArbazAbid, it happens all the time. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Thanks again, I will accept this as answered in 6 minutes, it won't let me accept now :)